# jsp, can't find source of css property

Tags: java, css, jsp

This may be a tricky question because I can't give much detail,
I'm working of legacy code on a big project (`in jsp`) and I came across a `"styleid = product"`.
It changes quite a lot of things when I remove it, but I can't seem to find it in any of the CSS files, there are properties like `"tdproduct"` and `"thproduct"` but I can't seem to find any connection.

Can anyone give me an indication of other places I might need to look for this (except `.css` files).
thanks in advance

Comment: Except css files? May be JSP file itself or in the jQuery/JavaScript?

Comment: It wouldn't hurt to do a solution-wide search for `styleid`..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you load the page in firefox/chrome browser? 
If so you can see the generated source code.
Since JSP is a server side technology that generates some dynamic content, its also possible that the CSS will be also generated dynamically.

Theoretically it can be JSP itself, the CSS and even Java Script :)
Good luck!

Hope this helps

Comment: `styleid = product` seems like a custom HTML attribute. Very unlikely it would have any CSS rules written against it..

Comment: it was idd in the jquery that is was used

Answer (score 1):

css are dynamically loaded when your page is loaded. your style classes can also be defined in the jsp that you are including in the parent jsp.

open the page in firefox and use firebug to view the styles loaded. You can locate where your style is loading from.